# how to insert generated id from response , into the endpoint

Tags: java, rest-api, json, api-automation

I'm testing API, using Rest assured, programming language is java. Is there any way to get the generated id from a response body and insert it into the endpoint?

I have the following endpoint `{baseUrl}/api/product/{id}/deleteActivity`

I want clean up after myself, every time when I create a new POST, its generating new id, I want to get that id put it in the endpoint, and delete the created product, so that I don't have to change the id every time manually.

```
response = when().request("Delete","{baseUrl}/api/product/{id}/deleteActivity");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RestAssured docs](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured#examples), you can do the following:

```
String json = post(URL_TO_CREATE_ENTITY).asString();
String id = from(json).get("generatedId"); // Or whatever is the name of the attribute with the ID
```

Then you can make a call with this value:

```
String urlToDelete = "{baseUrl}/api/product/" + id + "/deleteActivity"
delete(urlToDelete)
```

Comment: Thank you @João Farias

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory, could you mark it as Accepted, so other people will know it is the correct one?